# Blocking statements with @ExecuteOn as long-term solution?

Tags: micronaut

My question/concern is about using blocking statements as a long-term solution.

- We currently support a monolithic app running over *micronaut 3.x* and *JDK11*.
- We would like to upgrade to *JDK17* to be prepared for *micronaut 4.x*.
- We currently use a proprietary non-blocking framework in the form of an annotation processor which, to put it simply, cannot be supported by more recent JDK versions (and thus must be axed)
- We are faced with a difficult dilemma: refactor the entire codebase to reactor syntax, or force joins and blocks within the system while annotating all REST endpoints with `@ExecuteOn`.

I am aware that the latter approach will effectively hijack the thread *even when* the business logic is just waiting for I/O to finish (and thus the serve will effectively serve less requests in parallel). *But beyond that, is there anything else which I should be concerned about?*

Much appreciated.